# Jquery refresh new opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh new opened window, i have a link and when i click on it i open a new window , so i want to refresh and edit the new window url after 3 seconds.

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('/page/?q=param', '_blank');
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "/?q=new_value" );
}, 3000);
});
```

this code is refreshing the original page not the new one. so i want a way to refresh the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the new window reference and access location attribute.

`var newWindow = window.open('/page/?q=param', '_blank');`

You can do something like this

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newWindow = window.open('/page/?q=param', '_blank');
  setTimeout(function() {
    newWindow.location.href = newWindow.location.href.replace(/[\?#].*|$/, "/?q=new_value");
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
// set `popup` as reference to new `window`
var popup = window.open("/page/?q=param", "popup");

setTimeout(function() {
  // set `location.href` of `popup` 
  popup.document.write("<script>location.href = location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, '/?q=new_value');</script>")
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will refresh the original window, of course.
you have to change the code so you will assign a variable:

```
w =  window.open('/page/?q=param', '_blank');
```

the "window.location.href" will refresh the current window, not the other one, 
and then change it's location in the setTimeout:

```
w.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "/?q=new_value" );
```